# Name for relationship where a is related to b iff a and b are in different subsets

Tags: relations

Yesterday I was out running in the park, and like many others I always run in a counterclockwise direction around the central lake. There are also strange people who always run in a clockwise direction. I realized that all the runners I can recognize by face run clockwise, because they are the ones I actually meet regularly. I never meet the people who run in the same direction as I do.

So we have a set of runners that can be divided into two distinct subsets, and runner A and runner B can recognize each other iff they are *not* in the same group.

Is there a name for such a relation?

Comment: @GitGud : Such a relationship would not be reflexive.

Comment: I thought it was sort of the opposite of an equivalence relation, the equivalence relation would be the case where A and B were related if they were in the same group? It's also not reflexive or transitive. Does a "nonequivalence relation" exist?

Comment: You're all right. I misread the question (rather I didn't read it completely).

Comment: @GitGud: renamed the groups to distinct subsets

Comment: @RemcoGerlich the term "anti-equivalence relation" seems to be giving some results when I search it.

Comment: I don't think this has a name, but mathematically, the relationship looks to be $$A\times A^c \bigcup A^c \times A $$ where $A$ is the set of runners who run clockwise.

Comment: @GitGud: sure! there should be contact details on my profile.

Comment: **discrepancy** relations is the term you're looking for :)

An example, would be xor, $\{(p,q) \,|\, \text{ exactly one of } p,q \text{ is true }\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: the results I get in Google for anti-equivalence relation talk about relations that don't have any of the properties of equivalence relations, but this one is symmetric.

Comment: @Moses: I like the name a lot, but Googling doesn't show anything. If it's been used anywhere it should be an answer.

Comment: I recall seeing it mentioned by Backhouse et al as *the* name for xor, but I don't recall more general usage. I think it may be fine to use the term as it brings about connotations of distinctness ---just as the term equivalence brings connotations of similarity or identity. 

I don't know; hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

We call such a relation usually *'an'* orthogonality relation, e.g.:
$$A\perp B:\iff A\cap B=\varnothing$$

Comment: In this particular case, we probably want $$p \bot q \;:\equiv\; See(p) \cap See(q) = \emptyset$$ where $See(x)$ is the set of people that $x$ sees :)

Comment: Yes, for example that one ;) but that might be not enough as you'd maybe like to ask for more people simultaneously as do Eric, Gina and Ellison run all opposite to Luis, Carl and Anna...

Answer (score 1):

Let $J$ be the set of joggers, runners, and walkers etc. that run around the lake at the park. Define the relation $S$ on $J$ as

$$jSk\iff\text{ }j\text{ sees }k \text{ while jogging, running, or walking around the lake}.$$

Now a reflexive relation $R$ on a set $A$ is one such that $\forall a\in A,aRa$. Clearly $S$ is not reflexive since a person does not see themselves as they run.

A symmetric relation $R$ is one such that if $jRk$, then $kRj$. Note that $S$ meets this criteria because for each person you see, they see you. Thus $S$ is symmetric.

A transitive relation $R$ is one such that $jRk$ and $kRl$ implies that $jRl$. Note that the relation $S$ is not transitive. $jSk$ implies $kSj$ by the symmetry of $S$. That together with $kSl$ show that $k$ sees both $j$ and $l$. Thus $j$ and $l$ run in the same direction and do not see each other.

Finally, an antisymmetric relation $R$ is one such that $jSk$ and $kSj$ imply that $j=k$. Note that $S$ is not antisymmetric, If $jSk$ and $kSj$, the runners $j$ and $k$ see each other, and thus are not the same person.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, it's exactly the opposite of an equivalence relation, so it should be called "not equivalent".

It can be justified as follow:

-The relationship where object have the relationship when they are in the same partition is an equivalent class.

-The relationship where object have the relationship when they are not in the same partition is independence of the object to represent the class: that is if you pick $A,B$ from a class and $C,D$ from a class, the relationship of $A$ to $C$ is the same as that of $B$ to $D$.

-Hence you can factor out the equivalent class and made them into object.

-Once factored out, the relationship where object have the relationship when they are not in the same partition turn into the relationship where object have relationship with everything except itself: ie. "not identical" relationship.